# Get basename of a Windows path in Linux

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assume I have a string that hold a Windows file address, let's say

```
local_address = "C:\\TEMP\\filename.txt"
```

to retrieve the filename from the address above I use

```
import os
filename = os.path.basename(local_address)
```

In Windows, when I run the code the output is

```
>>> print filename
filename.txt
```

But when running the code in linux I get

```
>>> print filename
C:\TEMP\filename.txt
```

The reason is (what I think is) that when the Linux implementation of Python expects Linux local file address formats and has no idea about Windows addresses. Letting manual parsing of the address alone, are there other solutions so that I get uniform results?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python have multiple implementations of `os.path` module, and if you're lucky, your python may be equipped with `ntpath` module:

```
>>> import ntpath
>>> ntpath.basename(r'C:\TEMP\filename.txt')
'filename.txt'
```

According to [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) documentation:

> Since different operating systems have different path name conventions, there are several versions of this module in the standard library. The `os.path` module is always the path module suitable for the operating system Python is running on, and therefore usable for local paths. However, you can also import and use the individual modules if you want to manipulate a path that is always in one of the different formats. They all have the same interface:
>
> - `posixpath` for UNIX-style paths
> - `ntpath` for Windows paths

Comment: There is no `npath` module to import. Does this same code work on both Windows and Linux?

Comment: `ntpath`, not `npath`

Answer (score 4):

- On windows, the file separator (`os.sep`) is backslash (`\`). Slash is also accepted (Windows OS functions accept it)
- On Linux, the file separator (`os.sep`) is slash (`/`). Backslash is not accepted.

what would work would be `os.path.basename(local_address.replace('\\',os.sep))`

to turn the backslashes into slashes so `basename` can process it (and it would also work on windows: you'd replace something by the same thing)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.